# How to kill multiple processes on a remote server with bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I have this very simple bash code that should kill a list of `tail -f` processes on a remote server.

```
old_tailf_pids=`ssh root@$server "ps -ef | grep 'tail -f -n +1 /opt/wd' | grep root | grep -v grep | sed -e \"s@root *\([0-9]\+\) .*@\1@g\""`
echo $old_tailf_pids
echo "Killing old tailfs..."
ssh root@$server "kill -9 $old_tailf_pids"
```

Output:

```
4007 5281 5906 8265 8823 9918 10477 11587 12213 12753 13396 13976 14558 15985 16788 18128 18762 19412 20109 21393 28924 29487 31542 32155
Killing old tailfs...
bash: line 1: 5281: command not found
bash: line 2: 5906: command not found
bash: line 3: 8265: command not found
bash: line 4: 8823: command not found
bash: line 5: 9918: command not found
...
```

Seems like the SSH command killed only the first pid, and then tried to 'run' the rest of the pids. Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because there's newlines in there.

Comment: Try this: `ssh root@$server "xargs kill -9 <<< \"old_tailf_pids\""`

Comment: @melpomene makes sense. But I didn't see any in the 'echo $old_tailf_pids'.

Comment: Newlines will show when you use proper quoting as `echo "$old_tailf_pids"`

Comment: @anubhava works! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is evident from comments below the question that variable contains newlines after each process id, you may use this `xargs` command in remote `ssh`:

```
ssh root@$server "xargs kill -9 <<< \"old_tailf_pids\""
```